# Hive shell not loading

Tags: hive, classcastexception

While starting `hive` I am getting this exception. Please help me with this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader (in module: java.base) cannot be cast to java.net.URLClassLoader (in module: java.base)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.<init>(SessionState.java:374)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.<init>(SessionState.java:350)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliSessionState.<init>(CliSessionState.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:663)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.base@9-internal/Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-internal/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-internal/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@9-internal/Method.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Java9?
Java 9 Uses no longer uses java.net.URLClassLoader.
According to : http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/talks/prepare-for-jdk9-j1-2015.pdf

However, I was able to solve the issue by pointing Hive to JDK8.

**Since I am new to this site I am unable to post comments.

Comment: This should be a comment.